# Why is the shape of an array in a list in Python different when I refer to it via the list name of via the array variable?

Tags: python, iteration

train_images is a list [] populated with images ('im').
I iterate through the list (train_images) and I change the shape of every 'im' in this list. But why are the two shapes different? 'im' is the same as train_images[x], or isn't it?

```
for im in train_images:
    im = transform.resize(im,(50,45),mode='constant',anti_aliasing=True)
    im = image.img_to_array(im)
    im = im/255
    im = im.flatten()
    
print(train_images[0].shape) #(200, 180, 3)
print(im.shape) #(6750,)
```

Comment: `im` is just a local variable here.  It takes on the values from `train_images`, one by one, but it is not any sort of alias for the position in the list that the values originally came from.  One you assign anything to `im`, it no longer has any relation to the list at all.

Answer (score 1):

> 'im' is the same as train_images[x], or isn't it?

*If you were not reassigning `im` inside the loop*, then `im` would end up as the *last* value `in train_images` (i.e., `train_images[-1]`). That is already a different array from `train_images[0]`, but yes it would have the same `shape` (since they are slices of the same Numpy array).

However, in your loop body, you have assignments to `im`. The `for` loop construct sets the value of `im` at the beginning of each loop, but it's also replaced inside the loop... so the value that `im` has *after* the loop is the *last value that was assigned*, i.e. the result of the `flatten` operation.

(If you're confused as to why calling `.flatten` changes the `shape` of the data... I'm not sure what to tell you. Why do you think it's called "flattening"?)

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of how loops assign the name, see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html .

Comment: Thank you. I understand 'flattening', but I thought that by looping through train_images, that every image inside that array would have been flattened and that the shape of train_images[0] would also be 6750 and no longer the old values before applying the transformations in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The image that you have is a 3D array, it has (x,y,z). Therefore, when you flatten it, you are multiplying `x*y*z` and making them one "`line`" of continuous values, similar to a list `[1,2,3,4,...]`.

Since you reshaped the images to `50x45`, after flattening, it becomes `50*45*3=6750`.

***Note***

I noticed that you don't know what is flattening.

`[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]=>flatten=>[1,2,3,1,2,3]`

Comment: Thank you. I understand 'flattening', but I thought that by looping through train_images, that every image inside that array would have been flattened and that the shape of train_images[0] would also be 6750 and no longer the old values before applying the transformations in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`im` is a local variable. When you assign to it you don't change `train_images` in any way. Each time round your loop you create a modified copy and store it in `im`, then throw it away the next time round the loop. When you `print(im.shape)` you are printing the copy from the last time round the loop. But none of the previous copies were saved anywhere, and `train_images` was never modified.